# Created by and Modified By not visible to users in DVWP

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have an issue in SharePoint with a specific list displayed via the DataFormWebPart.

The issue is that Created By, Modified By and a custom site column (Person or Group) called DMS Owner (internal name: solMitInqWfDmsOwner) will not display for any user that I have found except for me. I can see the fields in SPD as well in the browser. All users that I have tested with that had less, equal and greater permissions could not see the column data in a DVWP. Thus the display is the same for all users except me.

Some details of where the fields are visible and not visible.

- In designer I can see the columns in the Data Source Details task pane. A server admin accessing the same page/webpart could not see the three fields in the Data Source Details task pane.
- If sort and filter is enabled on headers, all users can see filter options. Applying a filter does change the number of records if applicable.
- The XsltListViewWebpart does not have this issue. All users see all data normally.
- Other lists in the site do not have this issue.
- A fourth custom person and group field named DCBS Owner (Person or Group) is visible to everyone.
- Creating a new list and adding all the site columns does not duplicate the issue.
- Creating a template of the “Inquiries” list and creating a new list from the template does duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have been caused by the limitation on Lookup and Workflow columns. This includes People and Group columns. In my list, I exceeded the limit set in central admin. When the limit was increased, all views displayed the three fields mentioned in the issue description above.